# Combine multiple text files line by line in Python

Tags: python, linux, file-io

suppose I have text files a , b ,c

**file a**

```
1

2

3
```

**file b**

```
a

b

c
```

**file c**

```
d

e

f
```

I want to write an output file like:

```
1 a d

2 b e

3 c f
```

Anyway to write it in python or any commands in Linux?

Answer (score 3):

In the command line:

```
$ paste a b c
1   a   x
2   b   y
3   c   z
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` for this:

```
with open("filea") as f1, open("fileb") as f2, open("filec") as f3:
    for a, b, c in zip(f1, f2, f3):
        print " ".join(map(str.rstrip, (a, b, c)))
```

Comment: Actually there are a thousand of lines, not just a,b,c.